# Please show number of pending edits only when I have votes to cast

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

I manage to use all my votes suggested edit approval/rejection today, and would like the suggested edits number at the top to show up only when I actually have votes that I can cast. I've learned that that sort of highlighting means there is something for *me* to inspect, and it's always a bit of a crush to get that "Sorry, come back in 22 hours" notice.

So please, I'd like that number to only be visible when I have votes I can cast.

Comment: Are you referring the suggested edits approval?

Comment: @Yi Jiang, yes, it lives between `tools` and `chat`.

Comment: Does approving a proposed edit count against one of my vote allowances then? The regular 30-a-day, or my flag votes, or something else? I don't think it's close votes and I'm not 10K so I don't have mod-point-votes.