# Compress edit suggestions I've already voted on

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

If I vote on a bunch of suggested edits and few other users are reviewing there are two behaviors that waste my time:

- the orange indicator on the nav bar fails to recognize that there are edits I've already reviewed, and continues to indicate there are edits to review (though it's possible there's no action I can take) -- I have to visit the edits page to determine this!
- Upon visiting the edits page, I see fully expanded edits for which I must scroll to see that I've already acted.

Thus, two feature requests:

1. The edit queue indicator should show only the number of edits I have potential action on
2. Edits in the queue I've acted on should appear as "compressed" (shrunk to just the title, like when I'm the second accepter or rejecter).

Comment: I've [already requested part 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow), with a slight variation. Post your suggestion as an answer there, to keep the discussion in one place?

Comment: Agreed on both parts. I suggested something similar to your part 1, but it only makes sense after using up all the day's votes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85007/please-show-number-of-pending-edits-only-when-i-have-votes-to-cast -- here's hoping whoever fixes your part 1 gets mine in the same pass. :)

Comment: It'd also be nice if long posts, when accepted or rejected and moved to the top of list, didn't require me to scroll back up to find the next one in the list. :) And I also want a unicorn!